# Как добавить <line> к <svg> через JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

Есть `<svg>`, к нему нужно добавить `<line>`. Пытаюсь добавить через **JavaScript** - не получается. Добавляю точно такой же `<line>` напрямую через **HTML** - все получается.

**HTML**:

```
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
let nLine = document.createElement("line");

nLine.setAttribute("x1", "6.25vh");
nLine.setAttribute("y1", "0vh");
nLine.setAttribute("x2", "6.25vh");
nLine.setAttribute("y2", "80vh");

document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(nLine);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Так как SVG это по сути XML-документ, то элементы для него создаются в другом [пространстве имён](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS).
- Чтобы видеть объект, у него должны быть заданы ширина и цвет обводки (*stroke*) через атрибуты или CSS-стили.

```js
let nLine = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");

nLine.setAttribute("x1", "6.25vh");
nLine.setAttribute("y1", "0vh");
nLine.setAttribute("x2", "6.25vh");
nLine.setAttribute("y2", "80vh");
nLine.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1px");
nLine.setAttribute("stroke", "red");

document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(nLine);
```

```html
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

- Также неплохо было бы указывать для тега `<svg>` размеры и/или атрибут `viewBox`.

Comment: у меня  в личке ватсап - пиши